# Array sort before looping not keep the array sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have this code who simply create a array with html element and loop for parse the sort array.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
 var arrElementStyle = [];
 $('.bands-alphabetique [id*="band-style-"]').each(function(index){
  var style = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[2];
  arrElementStyle[style + '-' + index ] = $(this).find('.element'); 
 });
 arrElementStyle.sort();
 $('.bands-alphabetique').hide();
 for(style in arrElementStyle){
   $('.large-centered.col-md-12.clearfix').append(arrElementStyle[style]);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="large-centered col-md-12 clearfix">
  <div class="bands-alphabetique">
   <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-rock">
    <div class="element">
     <h1 class="band-style-title">Rock</h1>
     <a href="band.link">Fiction In Motion</a>
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-pop">
    <div class="element">
     <h1 class="band-style-title">Pop</h1>
      <a href="band.link">Marianas Trench</a>
    </div> 
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-pop">
    <div class="element">
     <h1 class="band-style-title">Alternatif</h1>
      <a href="band.link">Anberlin</a>
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I parse the html the result is not sort?(I want sort by style of music) Why? Want should I do.

Comment: your array is empty. You will never be able to sort an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you declared `arrElementStyle` as an array, but later you used it as an associative array for inserting data. So it is better to declare `arrElementStyle` as an object for this.

Here is an example demo of what I think you wanted to achieve with the help of `sort()` for sorting the objects keys:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    var arrElementStyle = {}; // declare arrEleemntStyle as object
    
    $('.bands-alphabetique [id*="band-style-"]').each(function(index) {
        var style = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[2];
        
        // push into object of key <style>-<index> the elements
        arrElementStyle[style + '-' + index] = $(this).find('.element');
    });

    // get the keys of arrElementStyle for sorting
    var keys = Object.keys(arrElementStyle),
        i, len = keys.length;
    console.log('before = ', keys);
    keys.sort(); // sort the object keys
    console.log('after  = ', keys);
    
    $('.bands-alphabetique').hide(); 
    
    // iterate the sorted keys and append it
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var k = keys[i];
        $('.large-centered.col-md-12.clearfix').append(arrElementStyle[k]);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="large-centered col-md-12 clearfix">
    <div class="bands-alphabetique">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-rock">
            <div class="element">
                <h1 class="band-style-title">Rock</h1>
                <a href="band.link">Fiction In Motion</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-pop">
            <div class="element">
                <h1 class="band-style-title">Pop</h1>
                <a href="band.link">Marianas Trench</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-pop">
            <div class="element">
                <h1 class="band-style-title">Alternatif</h1>
                <a href="band.link">Anberlin</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you're trying to sort an object.. not an array. So let's use an object and sort it's keys.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  // here's the issue I was saying about
  var elements = {};
  $('.bands-alphabetique').hide().find('[id*="band-style-"]').each( function( index ) {
    elements[ $(this).attr('id').split('-')[2] + '-' + index ] = $(this).find('.element');
  });

  var styles = Object.keys(elements);
  styles.sort();

  styles.forEach(function(style) {
    $('.large-centered.col-md-12.clearfix').append(elements[style]);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="large-centered col-md-12 clearfix">
  <div class="bands-alphabetique">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-rock">
      <div class="element">
        <h1 class="band-style-title">Rock</h1>
        <a href="band.link">Fiction In Motion</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-pop">
      <div class="element">
        <h1 class="band-style-title">Alternatif</h1>
        <a href="band.link">Anberlin</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-pop">
      <div class="element">
        <h1 class="band-style-title">Pop</h1>
        <a href="band.link">Marianas Trench</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not sorting an array. You have an object with different properties (style + '-' + index).

In other words, associative array does not exists in Javascript. What you really had was an object `arrElementStyle` with many properties.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
 var arrElementStyle = [];
 $('.bands-alphabetique [id*="band-style-"]').each(function(index){
  var style = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[2];
  arrElementStyle[index] = $(this).find('.element'); 
  arrElementStyle[index].bandStyle = $(this).find('.band-style-title')[0].innerHTML; 
 });
 arrElementStyle.sort(function(elementA, elementB){
        return elementA.bandStyle > elementB.bandStyle;
    });
 $('.bands-alphabetique').hide();
 for(style in arrElementStyle){
      $('.large-centered.col-md-12.clearfix').append(arrElementStyle[style]);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="large-centered col-md-12 clearfix">
  <div class="bands-alphabetique">
   <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-rock">
    <div class="element">
     <h1 class="band-style-title">Rock</h1>
     <a href="band.link">Fiction In Motion</a>
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-pop">
    <div class="element">
     <h1 class="band-style-title">Pop</h1>
      <a href="band.link">Marianas Trench</a>
    </div> 
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="band-style-pop">
    <div class="element">
     <h1 class="band-style-title">Alternatif</h1>
      <a href="band.link">Anberlin</a>
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```